# How to set hybridEnabled true in DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage alfresco solr?

Tags: solr, alfresco

Using Alfresco Community - 5.0.0 version.

**Use Case : For fetching documents we want to query Solr first then DB.**

First I've tried below properties in alfresco-global.properties file:

```
solr.query.cmis.queryConsistency=EVENTUAL
solr.query.fts.queryConsistency=EVENTUAL
```

After above changes, i was able to see logs that it was using Solr to execute Query and getting all the documents. But for some specific query, it returned no records.

So, for fixing above specific scenario, I've changed these from EVENTUAL to HYBRID.

```
solr.query.cmis.queryConsistency=HYBRID
solr.query.fts.queryConsistency=HYBRID
```

After these changes, there were no logs related to Solr or DB query and not getting any documents on UI.

After seeing the code of the DbOrIndexSwitchingQueryLanguage class, found that hybridEnabled attribute should be true for executing this case.

Can anybody suggest me how to set hybridEnabled true if this fix my problem or suggest anything else to resolve my use case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set **solr.query.hybrid.enabled=true** property for HYBRID searching.

> Pls see:
>   https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-repository/blob/ac38ac94ff4f9cbdf2671a9517781bda389a13c4/src/main/resources/alfresco/subsystems/Search/common-search-context.xml

Comment: If I use queryConsistency=EVENTUAL then it'll hit the Solr. 

If queryConsistency=HYBRID then it'll hit Solr and DB.

 

Is there any way to hit Solr first and if there are no results from Solr then it'll query the DB?